# Get post content by ID for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to fetch specific post content by ID for a custom post type.

I've tried the following solutions and a few more. At best I seem to be retrieving the title. But none of the content.

> 1:

```
<?php
$post_id = 15002;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

> 2:

```
<?php
$my_postid = 15002;
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

> 3:

```
<?php 
    $ID = 15002;
    $args = array('p' => $ID, 'post_type' => 'ct_template');
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php global $post; ?>
        <?php the_content () ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: have you tried dumping any variables?

Comment: I added $a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
var_dump($a); inside the bottom snippet and it came out fine I think: 

array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" } }

Comment: Your number two is correct, but I think you need to change `&gt;` to `>`. I have nearly the exact same code in a couple different files, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AndyWarren, nope nothing.

Comment: Is your post ID correct?

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure.

Comment: Here's the code I have in several locations, and it works. It's basically identical to yours. https://pastebin.com/0Furibci Are you using this code outside the main WordPress loop?

Comment: Well, as #2 is marked as a working solution on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/get-wordpress-post-content-by-post-id it should work. 15002 is a very high post id, so seems suspicious as mentioned by AndyWarren

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l6f5pi

Comment: Can you turn on [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and see if any PHP errors are present?

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the CPT's permissions. i.e. 'public' => true, ? Just a very wild stab in the dark.

Comment: That's possible @GavinSimpson: "The second one is public which is a predefined flag to show the post type on the administration screens and to make it show up in the site content itself, if it's queried for. "

Comment: Where would I check the CPT/change the permission?

Comment: I've got toolset installed. But I can't see anywhere that lists the ct_template custom post type

Comment: Alas I don't know what toolset is. Just had a quick squizz at it via google. There must be a file created somewhere with your CPT declared in it. You will have to follow the toolset docs to find out more.

Comment: After activating debug got this - Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of WP_Hook has no effect in /herme/bosnaweb/b27/ix.fhhcom/ulti/wp-content/plugins/oxygen/component-framework/components/classes/code-block.class.php on line 34

Comment: I think change your question title to include TOOLSET, as it's very relevant. Parhaps someone who uses it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Toolset` and want to get `content` by page Id then use below code in your `function.php`

```
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_content_template_output', 'get_content_template_id', 99, 4 );
function get_content_template_id( $content, $template_selected, $id, $kind ) {
    global $current_archive_template_id;   
    $current_archive_template_id = $template_selected; // $template_selected = current Content Template ID
    return $content;
}
```

Then use below code to get `title` and `content`

```
$content_template_title = get_the_title($current_archive_template_id);
$content_template_content = get_the_content($current_archive_template_id);
```